# Failing Kerberos Authentication with kinit on Windows (error: Network is unreachable)

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, windows-server-2019

I am running Active Directory on a Windows Server 2019 VM and I am logged into a Windows 10 VM which is part of the domain.

I want to generate a Kerberos TGT using kinit.exe (provided by JDK 16)

- KDC is configured for port 88
- both UDP and TCP ports are enabled
- Windows Server domain firewall is turned off
- Windows 10 domain firewall is turned off
- LDAP authentication using the same principal works fine

Problem:

[Command Prompt]

```
C:\Users\eugen>kinit
Password for eugen@EXAMPLE.COM:
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.connect(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:120)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.connect(DatagramSocket.java:341)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:408)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:214)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLDirContext.getAttributes(GenericURLDirContext.java:103)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbServiceLocator.lambda$getKerberosService$1(KrbServiceLocator.java:166)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:865)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbServiceLocator.getKerberosService(KrbServiceLocator.java:164)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.Config.getKDCFromDNS(Config.java:1344)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.Config.getKDCList(Config.java:1230)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:216)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:198)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:345)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:498)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.acquire(Kinit.java:248)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:134)
        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:96)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:576)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.connect(DatagramChannelImpl.java:1243)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.connectInternal(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:91)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.connect(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:118)
        ... 21 more
```

I think the issue is that the request doesn't reach the server. Any ideas of how I can identify the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for my problem.

**How the cause has been identified:**

Running "ping example.com" would return this

```
C:\Users\eugen>ping example.com
       Pinging example.com [12.0.12.200] with 32 bytes of data:    Reply from 12.0.12.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from
   10.0.10.185: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 12.0.12.200: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 12.0.12.200: bytes=32 time<1ms    TTL=128
       Ping statistics for 12.0.12.200:    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

but running "nslookup example.com" would return this:

```
C:\Users\eugen>nslookup example.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2001:477:1a02:1:64ff:fe63:41a9:5600

*** UnKnown can't find example.com: No response from server
```

^ I think this means that the DNS server knows how to resolve the domain to an IPv4 address and not an IPv6 **AND** that it prefers to resolve to an IPv6 (maybe there is a setting out there to make it behave like this). Please point any flaw in my logic.

**How the issue was solved:**

Went to Control Panel -> View network status and tasks -> Click on the active connection -> Properties -> Unchecked "Internet Protocol Version 6(TCP/IPv6)

After this, ran kinit again and I successfully received a TGT.

Comment: DNS servers do not "prefer" things. If they're asked for IPv4 addresses (`A` type records), they will return IPv4 addresses. If they're asked for IPv6 (`AAAA` query type), they'll return IPv6. If the client OS has both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity, it will issue both queries and merge the results based on the client's preference. (And if the server's admin doesn't want DNS to return an IPv6 address, they shouldn't have added that address to DNS...)

Comment: @user1686 Makes much more sense. Thank you for sharing this